# Textarea is not enabled even if I made [attr.disabled]="false" in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, textarea, input-field

I'm using ngModel for textarea, and I wish to enable and disable textarea based on condition. I binded in right way and the value also changing to **[attr.disabled]="false"**, but the field not enabling.

```
<textarea pInputTextarea
                        [attr.disabled]="condition"
                        [(ngModel)]="echangesInternesNotes"
                        (ngModelChange)="onEchangesInternesNotesChange()"></textarea>
```

[image: Inspected code in browser console]

Comment: seems to be working find, could you replicate issue in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-inputtextarea-demo-swppnh)?

Comment: @NarenMurali I just found the glitch, sometimes even a small glitch make us sick, I used [attr.disabled] in my code, so it is not working. I changed to [disabled] and now it is working

Comment: please answer your own question and close this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem, sometimes even a small glitch make us sick, I used [attr.disabled] in my code, so it is not working. I changed to [disabled] and now it is working.

```
<textarea pInputTextarea
                        [disabled]="condition"
                        [(ngModel)]="echangesInternesNotes"
                        (ngModelChange)="onEchangesInternesNotesChange()"></textarea>
```